# Different results of flip on select and on index-accessed table in kdb+

Tags: kdb

In a `q` session I've made a keyed table `t`:

```
q)/KDB+ 3.6 2018.05.17
q)f:flip (`a`b)!(1 2 3;4 5 6)
q)k:flip (enlist `k)!(enlist 101 102 103)
q)t:k!f;t
k  | a b
---| ---
101| 1 4
102| 2 5
103| 3 6
```

Then I've tried to make a query and it gives a nice results:

```
q)select a,b from t where k=101
a b
---
1 4
q)flip select a,b from t where k=101
a| 1
b| 4
q)flip flip select a,b from t where k=101
a b
---
1 4
```

But without `select`-syntax this gives an error:

```
q)t[101]
a| 1
b| 4
q)flip t[101]
'rank
  [0]  flip t[101]
       ^
```

Why can't I just make a simple `flip` on the same result as from `select` of the same data types?

```
q)type flip select a,b from t where k=101
99h
q)type t[101]
99h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the elements of dictionary `t[101]` aren't lists, but atoms.  So flip on a list of atoms fails.

Appending each element to an empty list first will work.

```
q)(),/:t[101]
a| 1
b| 4
```

Not necessarily something you want to do.  For a given dictionary output, the solution you probably want is `enlist`

```
q)enlist t[101]
a b
---
1 4
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to lookup using a table rather than a lookup using an atom:

```
q)t[([]k:(),101)]
a b
---
1 4
```

That would be the equivalent of `select a,b from t where k=101`

Comment: Oh.. this construct is a little bit heavier to me. But taking it apart: (),101 - is just enlist 101, ([] k:(),101) - makes a table with column k and enlisted 101, and then we quering with this our table t! Oh! That makes sense! Because of t is a dictionary k!f. Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: Correct. Also the reason people often use `(),` instead of `enlist` is not because they are interchangeable (they're not) but because `(),` only enlists when it needs to (the atomic case). In the cast of a list `(),` does not enlist the list whereas `enlist` would. Thus, if you wanted to lookup more than one value of k you could use `t[([]k:(),101 103)]` meaning that `(),` works regardless of whether you have one index or more than one

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I read it twice - a Tip in https://code.kx.com/q4m3/3_Lists/#351-joining-with and only now feel effects of `(),` and `,()` on practice